# React Js setup with web pack and ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, es6-module-loader

when in run this command

```
sudo npm i -D babel-core babel-loader babel-present-es2015 babel-present-react react-hot-loader webpack webpack-dev-server
```

i have got this error

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'babel-present-es2015' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'react-todos'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-D" "babel-core" "babel-loader" "babel-present-es2015" "babel-present-react" "react-hot-loader" "webpack" "webpack-dev-server"
npm ERR! cwd /home/moeez/Desktop/data/react-todos
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/moeez/Desktop/data/react-todos/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please help me to setup React Js thanks in advance

Comment: You have a typo: s/babel-present-es2015/babel-preset-es2015/

Comment: Not directly related to your problem here, but try not to sudo your npm...

Comment: @ajmajmajma i have tried it without sudo also but same error

Comment: @ManoloSantos what?, i have also written the same as u say ...

Comment: I'm not saying it's going to fix your error here (sorry), I just mean you shouldn't sudo if you can avoid it, it can cause a whole bunch of other problems.

Comment: You misspelled two of the packages you're trying to install.  `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-react` are the correct spellings.

Comment: @MichaelParker Thanks buddy

Comment: @ManoloSantos Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Installing node from their website so you can remove sudo, 
Also instead of present, try preset